# What is the name of the account "System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem" in Windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows, service, user-permissions, local-system-account

I created a Windows Service Application using VS2013 and set the property *ServiceProcessInstaller.Account* to *System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem* and the service don't run until I gave permission to the **SYSTEM** account.

But I'm doubting if that **SYSTEM** account is the same account refereed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx) or referred by this enum value: *System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem*.

Comment: "Local system" and SYSTEM are indeed two names for the same object.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks for your reply, can you give me some references where to read that? If you write an answer I will select your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MSDN article "LocalSystem Account"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The LocalSystem account is a predefined local account used by the service control manager. [...] It has extensive privileges on the local computer, and acts as the computer on the network. Its token includes the NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM and BUILTIN\Administrators SIDs; these accounts have access to most system objects.

This is drawing a subtle distinction; LocalSystem is the name of the account (as defined by the service control manager; it isn't really an account from the kernel's point of view) whereas SYSTEM is the name of the security ID associated with that account.

The upshot is that you have to use LocalSystem as the account name when creating or modifying services, but have to use SYSTEM when assigning permissions.  (Alternatively, you can grant permission to the Administrators group.)

Comment: Excellent answer Harry, very clarifying. Thanks you!